# How to check for any null field of Object in List<Object>?

Tags: java

I have a list of Object passed to a method as below.

```java
Student s = new Student (name,age,branch, year); // student prototype

public void log(List<Student> items) { }
```

Inside the method, I need to check for any `null` values in each student object and log that particular attribute which was null and the corresponding student object. Is there a way to check this other than using?:

```java
items.stream().anyMatch(item -> item.getAge() == null ? System.out.println());
```

In actual scenario, my object contains more than 30 attributes and if any of the attribute is null, I want to log that null attributes and its corresponding object.

Comment: is the Objects need to be replaced with list of items i need to stream through.?

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to check each field individually if you want to check them one-by-one and log if they are null.

You could use reflection to iterate over all fields, but I would question the applicability of such a use-case.

Note that primtives like `int age` cannot be null, so you wouldn't need to check for it. Plus, your usage of `anyMatch` is incorrect as `System.out.println` does not return a boolean